# mysql INSERT and combining $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2-3 questions regarding my sql `INSERT` and how to go about combining multiple `$_POST` into one field.

1. i'm having problems with my `INSERT` statement everything was working till I added `m_id=".intval($id)."`
2. for field `m_age` I need to combine/insert the following three `$_POST['month'] $_POST['day'] $_POST['year']` into it. Should I create a `var $age = $_POST['month'] + ...;` then insert `$age` into `m_age` separately?
3. same as 2. I want combine `$_POST['feet']` and `$_POST['inches']` into `m_height`

code:

```
$fields = explode(" ", "m_id m_pos m_name m_age m_btype m_height");
$query = "INSERT INTO meminfo SET m_id=".intval($id).", ".dbSet($fields, "m_" + $_POST['add']);
```

Comment: It's somewhat interesting, but very opaque how this is supposed to work. You need to  show the `dbSet()` function, explain the database table or the desired final SQL query, with some example data set maybe.

Comment: This seems like several separate questions.

Comment: @MatthewRead correct its is several question like i stated in my post "I have 2-3 questions"

Comment: @Mario I left that part of the coding out. If you re-read my question it says everything worked until I added `m_id=".intval($id)."` which would me dbSet works and the code was just not added since its not relevant to the question.

Comment: So am I place `m_id=".intval($id)."` in the statement correctly and if I was multiple $_POST to be INSERTED into one field do I need to create a var for those POST items?

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether they're truly separate or not.  Separate questions should be separate posts.

Comment: they're numbered 1. 2. 3. seems pretty straight forward to me. question 2 and 3 is just a general question if I should combine the $_POST's into a variable or not before INSERTing into the height and age field. And, the first question is just pretty much a structure question is that the proper way to INSERT multiple items into a table using the SET. i'm using a comma to separate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> everything was working till I added m_id=".intval($id)."

this is not true.

While `m_id=".intval($id)."` being correct statement,
a `dbSet($fields, "m_" + $_POST['add']);` one makes absolutely no sense.

but you are right, the dbSet() function is intended to be used like that

```
$_POST['m_id'] = $id;
```

and 'm_id' will be added to the set automatically. Same for the other artificial fields

However, adding an id (assuming autoincrement field) into insert query makes no sense.

Anyway, seeing your struggle with basic PHP syntax I am going to withdraw my proposal for using dbSet() function.
You have to write your inserts by hand, until you get familiar with them.
Otherwise no function will do no good for you.

The particular problem obviously coming from the `m_` prefix you are using for all your fields. A strange whim making things unnecessary complicated. You'd better get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what your dbSet() function looks like I can hazard a few guesses:

1. Your $fields array contains an m_id field, which you are already setting explicitly when you added the m_id=".intval($id)." portion.  This could be why you're having problems there.
2. You want to insert into an "age" field using month, day, and year?  Are you calculating the age based on those 3 parameters assuming they are a birthdate?  If so I'd say you probably are best off doing that calculation and assigning the result to an $age variable and using that in your insert.
3. Same as #2 although conversion of feet and inches to a combined total in one of those units is a simpler calculation and so could be done inline with your insert statement.

Basically when it comes down to 2 & 3 you can go either way but your code will probably be much more readable (and therefore maintainable by you and/or others in the future) if you separate out the calculations from the formation of the SQL query.

Comment: $age - the reason from wanting to put month, day, and year into one field and 'not' calculating is because I want to do the calculations when ever the month,day,year is pulled. So the age can always be current and up to date. 
m-id - thanks, I totally over looked that m_id was in the $fields. I'll removed and give it a try again.